# How are functions in JavaScript treated as variables?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

```
function b() {
   return "B";
}
function output(par){
    var l=par;
    alert(l);
}
output(b);
```

The result i get is:

```
function b() (
     return "B";
)
```

But when i define the variable "l" outside the function. Like:

```
function b() {
   return "B";
}
var l=b();
alert(l);
}
```

The result is "B";

How do i make the function behave like in the second case but inside the function, and why is not treating it in the same way?

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
var l = b();
```

...you are **calling** `b`, and assigning the result to `l`. If you wanted `l` to refer to the function object `b`, you would just say:

```
var l = b;
```

(Likewise, in your `output()` function, if you did `var l = par()`, it would display "B".)

Comment: Perhaps what he's looking for is `output(b());`

Answer (score 1):

In the first case: you send function b as a parameter into function output .
In the second case: you call the funcation b using "b()",so at this time the varaible l is B other than the function itself.